# BeautifulSoup HTMLparsingError between Python2 and Python3

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-2to3

I run a bs4 program on Python27, it works faultless, I am having a problem once I used Python3. I am using updated version of bs4 for both. The file I am running this on is html and I noticed the error is on a  tag. Is there a supporting module I need to update? like lxml?

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = open(directory +'\\'+ file)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
```

Here is the error:

```
...
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\html\parser.py", line 174, in error 
      raise HTMLParseError(message, self.getpos())
html.parser.HTMLParseError: unknown status keyword 'NKXE' in marked section, 
      at line 318, column 49
```

Always appreciate the help!

Comment: Check with your file handler once is it reading or not...

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for. Do you mean what is the "data" object? Because I see in python27 it's <open file 'C:\Users\....txt', mode 'r' at 0x000000000503A660>.

Comment: Then in python3 its TextIOWrapper: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Users\\....txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if installing html5lib

```
pip install html5lib
```

And then making the request like this fixes the issue.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = open(directory +'\\'+ file)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')
```

This has worked for me.

Comment: Looking at the error message closer you look to be using Anaconda so you may need to use conda instead of pip to install html5lib

Comment: I indeed use conda. Thanks Again.